# Retrieved data from one column of database table into Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, database, export-to-excel

I want to Retrieved data from one of the column of my table name "hote_line", the column name is "elite" and it contains data and I want to retrieve data only from the column "elite". It contains 15,346 names with some info. Is there any way to get that into my Excel so I can make some changes? Because I have to add some id number into each name and it will take long time to edit each name one by one.

Comment: Can't this be done with an update query?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the engine of the table to allow CSV export:

```
ALTER TABLE hote_line ENGINE=CSV;
```

Then,run this query which will export your column into a file called test.csv

```
SELECT elite
INTO OUTFILE 'test.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM hote_line
```

Excel can than import easily csv files.
Don`t forget to change the engine back to whatever it was,INNODB probably.

EDIT Try it like this:

```
SELECT elite
INTO OUTFILE 'test.csv'
FROM hote_line
```

Comment: got error# "The used table type doesn't support AUTO_INCREMENT columns"

Comment: error "Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @RajkumarDayamoy You don't have privileges on that user.

Comment: but this is my database "Access denied for user 'dayamoy'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/ Use a trial version of dbforge has the option to export directly to excel.